# How to run delayed_job's queued tasks on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, automation, delayed-job

I'm currently using the delayed_job gem to queue and run background tasks in my application. In the local system, I can just use `rake jobs:work` to run the queued tasks. However, when I deploy my app onto Heroku, I do not want to continue using the rake command. Instead, I want the rake command to be called automatically. Is there a way to do so, without paying for a worker in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I use [cron](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) with out problems (with django). All do you need is to configure as task the same command that you can execute after `heroku run` command.

Remember that cron time compute as worker time, be sure that command ends.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it without a worker.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier point saying you need a worker is right, however you do have free worker hours. There 750 free hours per month http://www.heroku.com/pricing#1-0. Given a 31 day month is 744 hours, you have at least 6 free worker hours to use each month.

If you use the workless gem https://github.com/lostboy/workless this will spin up the worker only when needed (i.e. jobs waiting in delayed_job), then close it down again. Works perfectly for my app, and 6 hours of background processing time a month is more than enough for my requirements.